# How to switch bundler version?

Tags: ruby, bundle

I thought the below command would switch `bundler` installation, but it actually raised an error.

```sh
$ bundle _1.10.6_ -v
Could not find command "_1.10.6_".

$ bundle -v
Bundler version 1.13.6

$ gem list | grep bundle
bundler (1.13.6, 1.10.6)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Why do you want to use the old version of bundler?

Comment: you should be able to use older version of bundler if you just change `ruby` version.

Comment: Are you looking to revert? If so, why?

Comment: What does `which bundle` show?

Comment: The result of `which bundle` is /Users/me/.rbenv/shims/bundle.

Comment: Sometimes gems require using an older version of bundler; e.g., rails 4.2.1 requires bundler < 2.0.  So if you are stuck using older versions of certain gems (for many possibly legitimate reasons), you may need an older bundler.

Answer (score 9):

To use different gem versions, you could use this pattern: `your-gem _version_`. For example, `bundle _1.10.6_ -v`.

Hope that will help.

Comment: this command not switches a gem version - it just setted up a new default one. So you probably will get TWO default bundler versions at the same time.