# Can't start brand new rails app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Trying to start up a brand new rails project with heroku, followed the steps in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5 and https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails6. Both times when I try to push to heroku master, I get

```bash
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Could not detect rake tasks
remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:  !     /tmp/build_4403463c/config/boot.rb:5:in `require': cannot load such file -- bootsnap/setup (LoadError)
remote:  !     from /tmp/build_4403463c/config/boot.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     from /tmp/build_4403463c/bin/rake:7:in `require_relative'
remote:  !     from /tmp/build_4403463c/bin/rake:7:in `<main>'
remote:  !
```

I've tried to surround the `bootsnap/setup` with a rescue, and it still hits this block.

Comment: are you sure you have `gem 'bootsnap'` in Gemfile

Comment: `ensure you can run \`$ bundle exec rake -P\` against your app`—well, can you?

Comment: Yep I double checked both of these, bootsnap is installed and I can run bundle exec rake -P locally, even in production mode. I can't check on my heroku cause I'm failing the first push which means the box is never even created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution, In `Gemfile.lock` I switched `RUBY VERSION` to `ruby 2.6.6p146` and `BUNDLED WITH` to `1.17.3`

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I have 3 bundler versions installed:

```
gem list bundler

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (2.2.5, default: 2.1.4, 1.17.3)
```

Though 2.1.4 being the default, it seems it is not what being used when I bundle install.

I run `bundle _2.1.4_ install` and then it updates my `Gemfile.lock`.

```
# git diff
BUNDLED WITH
-   2.2.5
+   2.1.4
```

Then the problem was gone when I `git push heroku main`. I found these links helpful in troubleshooting my issue: [Heroku Rails build failing due to Bootsnap and Rake issues](https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/kifmxx/heroku_rails_build_failing_due_to_bootsnap_and/gh8suzj/) and [How to switch bundler version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41500197/how-to-switch-bundler-version).